# Recyclerview fast scroll items disappear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscroll, fastscroll

I am using GridLayoutManager with recyclerview, when i fast [image] scroll down one item out of four visible grid items (bottom right ) is moved further down,

I am using this tutorial to implement fast scroll and fast scroll indicator [here](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I also have items that disappear when I fling really fast.

Answer (score 3):

Guess i've found the solution.

Looks like when the Recycled Views are attached to the Window again, their state is changed to Invisible (IDK why). All we have to do is make it visible again.

Fortunately, RecyclerView.Adapter class has a method to handle when a view is attached or reattached to the RecyclerView.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewHolder holder){
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        if(!holder.tv_1.getText().toString().contentEquals("#EMPTYVIEW"))
            holder.root.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Log.i("ATTACHED_VISIBILITY",holder.tv_1.getText().toString()+"\t"+holder.root.getVisibility());
    }
```

My ViewHolder class

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_1;
    TextView tv_2;
    ImageView iv;
    ImageButton bt;

    View root;

    ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        //setIsRecyclable(false);     //to prevent views from getting deleted. :-(

        tv_1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.aral_tv_title);
        tv_2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.aral_tv_stitle);
        iv=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.aral_iv);
        bt=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.aral_bt_more);

        tv_1.setTypeface(WorkActivity.mainTF);
        tv_2.setTypeface(WorkActivity.mainTF);

        root=v;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

For every `if` there should be `else`.

For example:
If you have a view which is visible in XML file by default but you are changing its visibility in code, you must supply the `else` otherwise RecyclerView will re-use the views and will show re-used views with different data.

```
if(somethingIsTrue) {
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
 view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```