# Android - Empty items generated on scroll in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a `RecyclerView` in order to show a list of different items. The problem is that on fast scroll items are being randomly generated empty, if i scroll up and down again a different item can be generated empty. It happens on my LG g2 and I've checked on LG g4 and it does not happens there.

This is what i mean by empty item:
[image]

This is my `onBindViewHolder` in my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    final int finalPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    final String url = results.get(finalPosition).getURL();
    viewHolder.tvUrl.setText(url.replaceFirst("^(http://|www\\.|http://|www\\.|https://)", ""));
    viewHolder.tvCopiedWords.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%1$d", results.get(finalPosition).getNumberOfCopiedWords()));
    viewHolder.tvPercents.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%1$d%%", results.get(finalPosition).getPercents()));
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(activity, ResultWebViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            i.putExtra("Process", process);
            i.putExtra("share", activity.getString(R.string.export_scan) + ":" + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                    + url + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                    + activity.getString(R.string.results_similarity, results.get(finalPosition).getPercents()) + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                    + activity.getString(R.string.results_copied_words, results.get(finalPosition).getNumberOfCopiedWords()));
            activity.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

If you need another piece of code in order to help comment it and I will add.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've found a fix for this behavior, here's the link. [Fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38258400/5206518)